# Github action run step if previous dependent was skipped

Tags: github-actions

I have this pipeline. If I skip the first build step with `inputs.only-deploy = true` and it succeeds, the notification is not sent.
In case it fails the notification works fine.
How can I fix the notification in case of success?
Thanks.

```
jobs:
  buildImageAndPush:
    if: ${{ !inputs.only-deploy }}
    uses: MY_WS/common/.github/workflows/build-publish-docker.yml

  deploy:
    needs: buildImageAndPush
    if: ${{ always() }}
    uses: MY_WS/common/.github/workflows/docker-deploy.yml

  notification:
    needs: deploy
    if: ${{ success() }}
    uses: MY_WS/common/.github/workflows/notification.yml
    with:
      status: SUCCESS

  notificationFailure:
    needs: deploy
    if: ${{ failure() }}
    uses: MY_WS/common/.github/workflows/notification.yml
    with:
      status: FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you not combine both notification jobs into one with an `if: ${{ always() }}`?

Comment: @Azeem the notifications are different, how can I do? maybe do you see another way to skip the first step?

Comment: In your above example, `notification` and `notificationFailure` jobs calling the same workflow that's why I suggested to combine both.

Comment: Please add the inputs of your workflow along with the logs showing the current behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jobs:
  buildImageAndPush:
    if: ${{ !inputs.only-deploy }}
    uses: MY_WS/common/.github/workflows/build-publish-docker.yml

  deploy:
    needs: buildImageAndPush
    if: ${{ always() && !failure() }}
    uses: MY_WS/common/.github/workflows/docker-deploy.yml

  notification:
    needs: deploy
    name: Success
    if: ${{ always() && contains(join(needs.deploy.result, ','), 'success') }}
    uses: MY_WS/common/.github/workflows/notification.yml

  notificationFailure:
    needs: deploy
    name: Failure
    if: ${{ failure() }}
    uses: MY_WS/common/.github/workflows/notification.yml
```